# DolphinDB: How to count the number of positive changes in an array?

Tags: sql, count, window-functions, dolphindb

Suppose there is an array [1,2,3,4,3,2,4], I want to calculate the sum of positive changes in this array with a window of size 3 and output [2,2,1,0,1].

Elements with the same value are not considered positive changes. For example, the output of the array [2,2,2,4,3,2,4] is [0,1,1,0,1].

How to achieve this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rolling` function as follows:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,3,2,4]
rolling(def (x) -> sum(deltas(x)>0), x, 3)
```

You can also use the `moving` function as follows:

```
moving(defg (x) -> sum(deltas(x)>0), x, 3)
```

Note that the `moving` function returns NULL for the first (window - 1) windows and parameter func must be an aggregate function.

```
offset  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0           2   2   1   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dropna` to exactly match your expected length of result:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,3,2,4]
dropna(msum(dropna(deltas(x) > 0, 2)))
```